# C# Timed function

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, timer

I have the following problem:

I need to run a function search (depth x) that basically searches a decision tree until a certain depth and then returns (or leaves in a class member) a value of type Move.  At the same time I would like to be able to "cancel" the execution of the search if it goes on for too long.

It is also important that I don't have to wait for it if the search does finish faster. I realize this is not a complicated but I am not really familiar with C# concurrency controls.

Comment: and the code you've tried thus far is...?

Comment: At the moment my code exists for doing this without a timer, I am not sure how to modify this to have the option of early termination.

Comment: Could you share your piece of code with us?

Comment: [Cancel an Async Task or a List of Tasks (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj155759.aspx)

Comment: Both the `backgroundworker` and `Task` async implementations support cancellation (though by different approaches, one by `bool` and other by `token`). I suggest using `Task` as it is a newer approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example as starting point:

```
public class Runner
{
    private Task<int> search(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var t_work = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
        {
            int k = 0;

            while (k < 1000)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return -1;
                }                    
                k += r.Next(200);
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
            return k;

        }, ct);
        return t_work;
    }

    Random r = new Random();

    public async Task SearchAsync()
    {
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        var ct = cts.Token;
        var searchValue = await search(ct);
        string result = (searchValue < 0) ?
            "Search aborted without results" : "search value is: " + searchValue.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

you can use it in a console app like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("test");
var r = new Runner();
r.SearchAsync().Wait();
r.SearchAsync().Wait();
r.SearchAsync().Wait();
r.SearchAsync().Wait();
Console.WriteLine("done..");
```

Comment: why the downvote ? It is a mini example of a timed c# function as was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Task` for this, as it has built in mechanisms to handle errors, cancellation, and running `Continuation Tasks` when the task completes.

Assuming a custom return type of Move which I think you implied in your question:

```
private Task<Move> _searchTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _searchCancellationTokenSrc;
```

Then on a button click or similar, kick off your task. This will return immediately, keeping your UI responsive:

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _searchCancellationTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = _searchCancellationTokenSrc.Token;

    _searchTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
         {
             if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
             {
                 // Clean up here
                 ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
             }
             // Time consuming processing here
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
         }
         return new Move();
    },ct);

    _searchTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

    _searchTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Faulted. t.Exception contains details of any exceptions thrown");               
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    _searchTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Completed t.Result contains your Move object");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

To cancel this, perhaps from another button:

```
 private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      _searchCancellationTokenSrc.Cancel();
 }
```